# Ruby - Can I skip a line of input from the console and start reading from the next line?

Tags: ruby, console

I'm practicing some Ruby exercises on HackerRank and one of the challenges is to separate a string based on the value of each character's index. Essentially, even indexed characters go into one string an odd characters go into another. I've already written the main chunk of the code and I'm confident that it works, but I need help with reading the input from the console.

The input is as follows:

```
2
Hacker
Rank
```

The first line of input is the number of strings to perform the action on, and then it's followed by the two strings. I saw that there was a comment provided in the code that said to read input from STDIN, but I've only learned "gets" so far. And when I tried to use "gets", it was only grabbing the line of input that says "2". Is there a way to skip over the first line of input and go straight to the first string? I'll provide the rest of my code below just in case anyone needs it:

```
str = gets
puts str 

evens = ""
odds = ""

arr = str.split("")

arr.each.with_index do | letter, indx |
    if indx.even?
        evens += letter
    else
        odds += letter
    end 
end

puts evens + " " + odds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read words like this:

```
puts 'Number of words:'
words = []
number_of_words = gets.to_i
number_of_words.times do |i|
  puts "Word #{i + 1}:"
  words << gets.chomp
end
p words
```

Output:

```
Number of words:
2
Word 1:
Hacker
Word 2:
Rank

p words
#~> [Hacker", "Rank"]
```